# PHP loading issue "redirected too many times"

Tags: php

**localhost redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

My code was working perfectly fine, but today this error occurred not quite sure why. I have cleared browsing data, deleted cookies but nothing works. The rest of my site is functioning well, just this user login page. I am using PHPstorm.

```
 <?php
 include_once("db.php");

 if (isset($_POST['Login'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $path = "home.php";
    $select = "SELECT * FROM finalflight.tbl_book 
            WHERE email='" . $email . "' 
            AND ContactNo='" . $password . "'";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $select); 
}



if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['BookedBy'];
    $_SESSION['ContactNo'] = $row['ContactNo'];
    $_SESSION['bookid'] = $row['SrNo'];
    $_SESSION['uid'] = session_id();
    $path = "home.php";
} else {
    $path = "login.php?msg='unable to login'";
}
header("location:$path");
```

I have attached the error message screenshot. I am intrigued to know why the error has occurred wondering if someone could explain what is actually going on. PHPstorm came up with a redirect link for my page which I copied to clipboard and pasted it into my browser but that didn't seem to work. Is this a programming issue or a web browser issue? I have checked through my code and there doesn't seem to be any errors. I have tried reloading the web browser many times, deleted history nothing seems to work.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYIgN.png)

Comment: did you close mysql connection? if not then add mysqli_close($conn); before header("location:$path");

Comment: Hi I added it but still comes up with an error when loading.

Comment: Check this out.  If `$_POST['Login']` is not set, you send the user to `login.php?msg='unable to login'`.  So they come back to this page.  And again,  `$_POST['Login']` is not set, so you send the user to `login.php?msg='unable to login'`.  So they come back to this page.  And again, ...

Comment: And your second if should be inside the first one.  No need to do anything with the database if `$_POST['Login']` is not set.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `header` function while page leading that's why too many redirections. call `header` after post submitted

try this,

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");
if (isset($_POST['Login'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $path = "home.php";
    $select = "SELECT * FROM finalflight.tbl_book 
            WHERE email='" . $email . "' 
            AND ContactNo='" . $password . "'";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $select); 

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['BookedBy'];
        $_SESSION['ContactNo'] = $row['ContactNo'];
        $_SESSION['bookid'] = $row['SrNo'];
        $_SESSION['uid'] = session_id();
        $path = "home.php";
    } else {
        $path = "login.php?msg='unable to login'";
    }
    header("location:$path");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser will tell you what is going wrong if you dig a bit deeper. Likely your PHP error logging is trying to tell you about some of the problems too.

At a guess, The code you've shown us is probably working OK, but the page you are redirecting to is sending you back to this page - but you should NEVER REDIRECT TO THIS CODE! Actually, the code you've shown us should be re-written to handle the case where it is retrieved without the required POST vars without going completely pear-shaped.

Use the network monitor in your browser to see where you are getting 302 responses and where they are directing you to. Make sure your error logging is working properly and recording errors.